# Selenium webdriver - script is not worked with chrome but it is worked with firefox

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

This code is working with firefox but not working with chrome. Without change any thing it is working fine in firefox. I have used implicit and explicit nothing is working with chrome. Is anything i want to check with environment

```
WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(browser, 15);
wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable((By.cssSelector("input[name='ctl00$cphMainContent$imgAdd']"))));

//  browser.findElement(By.id("cphMainContent_imgAdd")).click();
browser.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='ctl00$cphMainContent$imgAdd']")).click();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(browser, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("span[id='tab3']")));
```

error message -

> unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (332, 548). Other element would receive the click:
>
> ...
>
> (Session info: chrome=42.0.2311.152)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.15.322448 (52179c1b310fec1797c81ea9a20326839860b7d3),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 39 milliseconds

Comment: Its not issue of chrome , its issue of your code I think.

Answer (score 1):

Could be possibly one of these reasons -

1. Object not loaded completely and click is performed
2. Chrome window is not maximized and chromedriver could not locate the element correctly.

Possible Solutions -

1. Increase sleep timer using `Thread.sleep(40000);` - Try this for debugging to the root cause of the issue
2. Maximize the chrome window - `driver.manage().window().maximize();`
3. Try to use javascriptexecutor for scrolling to the object and then click

Comment: +1 for suggesting javascript scrollIntoView.


I would also suggest (as a last resort) just using javascript to click the element when using chrome driver.  Chrome and IE driver are lot more picky about their click actions than firefox is, which is why you're seeing this error only in chrome.